# Tomcat cannot find the Postgres driver

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc

I have a webapp in Tomcat which connects to a PostgreSQL database. I have included the JDBC PostgreSQL driver in the `lib/` folder of my webapp. The IDE I am using is Eclipse.

I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.driver
```

Relevant code snippet:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.driver");
String connectionUrlString = "jdbc:postgresql://server_addr:5432/db_name";
Connection dbConnection = null;
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection (connectionUrlString, username, password);
```

Comment: Why do you do that "manually"? That should be handled by the connection pool.

Comment: ^ What exactly do you mean?

Comment: In a JavaEE application database connections should not be managed manually within the code, but should be provided through a connection pool that is configured outside of the application (e.g. in Tomcat in `context.xml`)

Comment: Any links I can read up?

Comment: The Tomcat documentation, the Oracle JavaEE tutorials, any JavaEE/Web tutorial...

Comment: [JNDI datasource](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) is the term, that you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with a capital `D`:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

Comment: Stupid me! I'll try this tomorrow as I don't have access to the server now. I'll update you ASAP.